# C++ pointer-to-method template deduction doesn't compile when targeting x86, but works with x64

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member, member-functions, template-argument-deduction

I've got this sample code:

```
struct A
{
    int foo() { return 27; }
};

template<typename T>
struct Gobstopper
{
};

template<>
struct Gobstopper<int(void)>
{
    Gobstopper(int, int) { }    // To differentiate from general Gobstopper template
};

template<typename ClassType, typename Signature>
void DeduceMethodSignature(Signature ClassType::* method, ClassType& instance)
{
    // If Signature is int(), Gobstopper<> should resolve to the specialized one.
    // But it only does on x64!
    Gobstopper<Signature>(1, 2);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A a;
    DeduceMethodSignature(&A::foo, a);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles fine with `g++`. It also compiles fine with VC10, but only when building for the 64-bit platform. When I build for the 32-bit platform, I get this compile error:

```
error C2661: 'Gobstopper<T>::Gobstopper' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=int (void)
1>          ]
1>          c:\...\test.cpp(26) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void DeduceMethodSignature<A,int(void)>(Signature (__thiscall A::* ),ClassType &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Signature=int (void),
1>              ClassType=A
1>          ]
```

The error indicates that the non-specialized version of Gobstopper is being used, which must mean the `Signature` is something other that `int (void)`. But the error also clearly says that `Signature` *is* `int (void)`. So where does the error come from? And how can I fix it?

The only thing I can think of that might change from 32-bit to 64-bit and not show up in the signature displayed in the error message is the calling convention; apparently, [there is a unified calling convention for VC x64, whereas for x86 each calling convention is distinct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention). But even if that's the problem, I have no idea how to fix it.

Edit: I should mention that I tried this with regular (non-member) function pointers, and that worked fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are quite correct.
The type of `Signature` with a Win32 target is `int __thiscall(void)` while on x64 it is `int __cdecl(void)`. Note that on either target the type of non-member functions commonly called `int(void)` is indeed `int __cdecl(void)` so, by coincidence one of the constructed types actually (not really correctly!) matches.

In general it is not advisable to mix the different types of function pointers by template magic, so the Gobstopper specialization should look at something like `int (ClassType::*)()` instead.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for confirming my suspicions (how did you check, by the way? I'm finding it quite tricky to debug template arguments). Is there any way I can separate the calling convention from `Signature`? I don't actually use `T` within Gobstopper to define a function pointer, merely as a means of disambiguating template specializations. Also, not to nitpick (OK, to nitpick), but isn't the calling convention on x64 `__thiscall` as well, but it happens to be compatible with `__cdecl`?

Comment: Actually, the 32 bit convention for VC++ is cdecl for "normal" functions and thiscall for member functions. On 64 bit Windows, it is neither the cdecl nor thiscall known from the 32 bit environment, but something different utilizing even more registers than thiscall for both kinds. If you would like to know more, consider consulting http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf where pretty much every calling convention in use is listed.

Comment: Oh, and on VS you can use `typeid(T).name()` to give you the name of a type - even if it is a template argument.

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thanks! I just wish there was a way to ignore or change the calling convention of `Signature` somehow...

Comment: Sadly, the calling convention is not really everything... The standard makes member functions (and pointers to members) very different from non-members, so again my advice to not even attempt this mixing ;)