# Pointer-to-member as template parameter deduction

Tags: c++, class, templates, parameters, pointer-to-member

I want to get pointer-to-member as template parameter to the foo1. Here is code:

```
struct baz{
    int qux;
};

template<typename C, typename T, T C::*m>
struct foo1{};

template<typename C, typename T>
void barr2(T C::*m){
}

template<typename C, typename T>
void barr1(T C::*m){
    barr2(m); // ok
    foo1<C, T, &baz::qux> _; // ok
    foo1<C, T, m> f; // g++4.6.1 error here; how to pass 'm' correctly ?
}

int main(){
    barr1(&baz::qux);
}
```

So how it should look like?

Comment: See also [my own related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729438/c-pointer-to-method-template-deduction-doesnt-compile-when-targeting-x86-but). The short answer is that you can't do it *portably*, as far as I know, but it should work if you just want to target GCC or VC++ x64. Wait, nevermind, you're not doing method pointers but rather data member pointers. Forget I said anything!

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't work for you because you are trying to use run-time information in a compile-time expression. It is the same as using integer that you read from console to specialize a template. It is not meant to work.

It doesn't necessarily solve your problem, but if the intent of `barr1` function was to ease typing burden, something like this may work for you:

```
struct baz{
    int qux;
};

template<typename C, typename T, T C::*m>
struct foo1 {};

#define FOO(Class, Member)                                  \
    foo1<Class, decltype(Class::Member), &Class::Member>

int main(){
    FOO(baz, qux) f;
}
```

Comment: i might misunderstood something but this compiles:[http://pastebin.com/XVWzLSdR](http://pastebin.com/XVWzLSdR)

Comment: passing the parameter directly is not a problem. i'm interesting in passing parameter exactly as in a given example (also, look at the link above).

Comment: @mirt: That is exactly what you cannot do. Pointer to member is just an address in memory. Thus, it can be used to specialize a template only in case of constant expression. Function arguments are not constant expressions.

Comment: example updated. i still don't understand the principal diffirence bettwen code that marked as 'ok' and that which one not compiles.

Comment: @mirt: The one which does not compile tries to pass a run-time variable as a template parameter. The one which does compile does not.

Comment: Ok, that's right. but  compiler know all the components of pointer-to-member type and my question is how to pass it correctly as parameter to template.

Comment: Hm, now i think that it is not right. That is all a compile time info.

Comment: Tell me more about how could i instantiate templates at runtime.

Comment: And again i think you right. But it is not cancelled my question.

Comment: @mirt: Simple answer is you can't. Templates are instantiated at *compile time*, once you move to *runtime* the compiler is no longer there and cannot help you. You might think that this is all resolved at compile time, well, it is not truly. There is a single `barr1` function instantiated for a given combination of class and member types, and it might be passed multiple pointer-to-member referring to different members. Note the problem: single `barr1` but you expect *multiple* different definitions. Consider `void f(int x){int a[x];}` which is the same problem even if it might look different.

Comment: C++17 now allows you to use auto in template paramters. I suggest using `template <auto N>`.