# Having Pointer Template and Pointer To Member Function as Template Arguments in C++03

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, c++03

I want to define a template class with 2 template arguments:

1. A pointer type T*
2. A pointer to a member function of the underlying type T

Additionally I would like to set a default method for the function argument.

```
// Do not allow SortedLinkedList<T>
template<typename T, bool (T::* comparisonMethod)(const T&) = &T::lessEqual>
class SortedLinkedList
{
private:
    SortedLinkedList();
};

// Allow SortedLinkedList<T*>
template<typename T, bool (T::* comparisonMethod)(const T&)>
class SortedLinkedList<T*>
{
public:  
    void insert(T* item)
    {
        // do something with /item->*comparisonMethod)(...))
    }
};
```

This code does not compile, because g++ (4.4.3) can not deduce the underlying type of `T*`

```
error: creating pointer to member function of non-class type ‘T*’
```

Is there a way to deduce the underlying type already in the class declaration? `decltype` is not available in C++03 and I don't know if it would work at this place.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182088/pointer-to-member-as-template-parameter-deduction), but it does not help in this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Problem

The reason it fails to compile is that the compiler will check to see that the *primary-template* is a viable match **before** it goes on to see if there is any *specialization* that is a more suitable alternative.

This means that when you try to instantiate `SortedLinkedList<A*>`, the compiler tries to see if the declaration `bool (T::* comparisonMethod)(const T&) = &T::lessEqual`, in the *primary-template*, is well-formed having `T = A*` - which it obviously isn't (since pointers can't have member-functions).

---

#### A Solution

One way to solve this issue is to add a level of indirection, so that both the primary template - and the specialization - yields a well-formed instantiation.

```
template<class T> struct remove_pointer     { typedef T type; };
template<class T> struct remove_pointer<T*> { typedef T type; };
```

```
template<class T>
struct comparison_method_helper {
  typedef typename remove_pointer<T>::type Tx;
  typedef bool (Tx::*type)(Tx const&) const;
};
```

```
// primary-template
template<
  class T,
  typename comparison_method_helper<T>::type = &remove_pointer<T>::type::lessEqual
> class SortedLinkedList;

// specialization
template<typename T, typename comparison_method_helper<T>::type func>
class SortedLinkedList<T*, func> {
  public:
    void insert (T const& item) {
      (item.*func) (T ());
    }
};
```

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  bool lessEqual (A const&) const {
    std::cerr << "hello world\n";
    return false;
  }
};

int main () {
  SortedLinkedList<A*> ().insert (A()); // outputs 'hello world'
}
```